# Tiny flash for dslr without built in flash

Tags: flash

I’m searching for a tiny flash that can stay on top of a canon 5D Mark II even when packed away and basically live on the camera. Ideally something as small as the [FlashQ](https://m.dpreview.com/articles/1805301255/flashq-the-little-cube-for-flash-photography) remote trigger. How good the flash is is less important.

The intent is to have a flash always on the camera when needing one when not expecting it.

What is the closest I can get to such a product?

Comment: Like Fuji’s EF-X8? http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-FucfKyRvfjo/U2pPHNdJvuI/AAAAAAAAN3g/Xs8gGszhIEw/s1600/flashbl.jpg

Comment: Maybe, an option at least if it will work on a canon camera. Would it do that?

Comment: Can’t edit anymore, but don’t get that flash for anything but the Fuji X-T series, it doesn’t work on anything else. Just wondering if that’s what you’re looking for.

Comment: Metz Mecablitz 26 AF-2 perhaps? (Not sure if that's best, hence comment. Anyone, feel free to use comments in your answer in any way)

Comment: Why not use a very small flash, such as the already suggested 26 AF-2 or the Speedlite 270EX II? granted, they may be a bit big for staying on top when having the camera in a bag - but if the camera is in a bag, then you might just as well put the flash in it, too ;-) also, `How good the flash is is less important` is only true if it is any good at all - a flash that does not work most of the time isn't necessarily better than no flash.

Comment: For future reference, [tag:compactflash] is about CF storage card, not illumination.

Comment: The 26 af-2 seems ok, I had already been looking at it but was hoping for smaller. Thanks all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing available as small as the "flashq" that works as a flash.

The Canon 90EX as it is the smallest flash available that is fully compatible with your 5D Mk II. It has just a little less power than most built-in flashes

[image]
<sub>Canon 90EX</sub>

Power: Guide No (ISO 100) 30'/9m (at 24mm)
Size: 1.7" x 2.0" x 2.6"
Weight: 2.570 oz. with two AAA cells 
(1.8 oz. empty)

---

The 270EX or 270EX II is also fully compatible with your 5D Mk II, is only slightly larger, but has much more power. It also recycles faster and has a tilt-up head for bounce flash.

[image]
[image]
<sub>Canon 270EX</sub>

Power: Guide No (ISO 100) 89'/27m (at 50mm) 72'/22m (at 28mm)
Size: 2.6" x 2.6" x 3.0"
Weight: 7 oz. with two AA cells (5.6 oz. empty)

---

The 220EX is also a pretty good option. It recycles faster because it uses 4 AA batteries but that also makes it a little bit larger and heavier.

[image]
<sub>Canon 220EX</sub>

Power: Guide No (ISO 100) 72'/22m (at 28mm)
Size: 3.6" x 2.6" x 2.4"
Weight 9.0 oz. with 4 AA batteries. (5.6 oz empty)

Comment: Accepting this as the answer that there is no such flash seems to be the case. Thanks